# JQuery bind is not working in IE8

Tags: jquery

**I have this code in JQuery:**

```
$(function (){
                        $("#TxtName").bind('input',function(){
                            if(/[~!@#$%^&*)(_+÷×A-Za-z0-9+-\.]/.test(this.value)){
                                $(".char_test_TxtName").css("visibility","visible");
                                $(this).val('');
                            }else{
                                $(".char_test_TxtName").css("visibility","hidden");
                            }
        });
    });
```

**Can somebody tell me why the bind is not working in IE8?**

Comment: Which version of jQuery you are using?

Comment: bind is not supported in IE8 or lower

Comment: @Satpal jQuery Version 1.9.1

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `.bind()`.

Try like this:

```
 $("#TxtName").on('input',function(){
```

Comment: I tried this code but did not answer

Comment: @mohammadbana:- What is the issue you are getting?

Comment: To filter out the keyboard and display only the characters considered appropriate message

Answer (score 0):

The [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) documentation suggest to use add the following code at the beginning of your script to partially support the bind() method in browsers that do not (fully) support it:

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
  Function.prototype.bind = function(oThis) {
    if (typeof this !== 'function') {
      // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5
      // internal IsCallable function
      throw new TypeError('Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable');
    }

    var aArgs   = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
        fToBind = this,
        fNOP    = function() {},
        fBound  = function() {
          return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP
                 ? this
                 : oThis,
                 aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
        };

    fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

    return fBound;
  };
}http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport
```